# React appends 'px' to stop-opacity css value

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSX that renders a linear-gradient svg tag:

```
return (
  <linearGradient id={props.name} x1={x1} y1={y1} x2={x2} y2={y2}>
    <stop offset='0%'
      style={{
        stopColor: props.color,
        stopOpacity: 0.3
      }}
    />
  </linearGradient>
);
```

When this is rendered, react automatically appends 'px' to the value of the stop-opacity rule, which not valid CSS.

```
<linearGradient x1="0%" y1="100%" x2="0%" y2="0%">
  <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#FDDE90; stop-opacity:0.3px;"></stop>
</linearGradient>
```

How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `stopOpacity` to the list of css styles that are a number but don't include "px". In the react source code, search for `isUnitlessNumber` to find the list.

Comment: Correct. I found that earlier and submitted a pull request which was merged into the main repository. The fix will be in the next version of react.
The pull request is here: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/4577#issuecomment-128401759
I forgot to update this question. Accepting this answer.